# How to get the list of the kernel parameters which are supported by the actual kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, parameters

How can I get the list of all the possible kernel parameters which are supported by the actual kernel?

Comment: I doubt it is possible to get this list because the kernel simply ignores parameters it does not know and makes them available to the init process, and because the kernel is expanded by modules which it might know nothing about until the module is loaded (ie any parameter with a "." in the parameter name) - and of-course, modules can be compiled after the kernel is running.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I am experimenting with the "failsafe" parameter, which is supported by AntiX, but I don't know if my ArchLinux32 system does support it.

Comment: I don't think that's a standard kernel command - according to Antix documentation its equivalent to load=all
blacklist=VIDEO
from=all
xorg=safe

Comment: You might want to post about the problem you are trying to solve rather then an abstraction of how the kernel behaves (but I applaud your obvious efforts to understand things and solve the problem yourself)

Comment: I have posted my original problem on many forums, but I got no help: my Linux PC simply freezes after it prints "Loading initial ramdisk". The most interesting thing is that it freezes only at autumn and winter, nearly never in summer. So I think some electronic device on the mainboard shows an influence of the temperature. Furhermore when I let my PC switched on for a few minutes in the frozen state, and then I reboot, then it can start normally again, doesn't freeze. So it can warm up.

Comment: Have you considered a failing power supply as a possible source? This sounds very much like a blown cap somewhere, and PSUs are a prime candidate.

Comment: PSU is first class, works flawlessly, maybe a blown capacitor. 2.4 GHz P4, Intel D865PERL mainboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85212/discussion-between-konstantin-and-davidgo).